# The ServiceClass object does not implement the required method in the following form: OMElement login(OMElement e)

Tags: web-services, apache-axis

After i upgraded the axis2 from 1.6.2 to 1.7.0 i get the following exception:

"The ServiceClass object does not implement the required method in the following form: OMElement"

most of the answers I found suggest to set the rpc message receivers in services.xml which i already had from previous version:

```
<service name="LogService" scope="transportsession">
<description>
    Log
</description>
<messageReceivers>
    <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-only" class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver"/>
    <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-out" class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver"/>
</messageReceivers>
<parameter name="ServiceClass">
    com.viaMEDICI.viaWS.services.LogService
</parameter>
```

Any other ideas what could have gone wrong? List services and the wsdl looks fine.

LE:

something different is the namespace before was "axis2ns2" now it is "nsoMZdG". No idea where could this come from.. and also i don't get all parameters by calling the ws restful and just only the first one...

Answer (score 4):

As noted in the [Apache Axis2 1.7.0 release notes](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/release-notes/1.7.0.html), the `http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/XXX` MEP URIs are no longer supported. Use `http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/XXX` instead.

Comment: Hi Andreas! Thanks for your response, i've already tried that too, didn't change the result. I've red also the release notes and upgraded to 1.7.1 because of the problems found in 1.7.0, and managed to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue

I solved it by updating 
http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-only  to http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/in-only
and 
http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-out  to http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/in-out

**Example services.xml**

*Earlier*

```
<service name="Axis2HelloWorld" >
    <Description>
        Please Type your service description here
    </Description>
    <messageReceivers>
        <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-only" class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver" />
        <messageReceiver  mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-out"  class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver"/>
    </messageReceivers>
    <parameter name="ServiceClass" locked="false">com.ciber.webservices.Axis2HelloWorld</parameter>
</service>
```

*New*

```
<service name="Axis2HelloWorld" >
    <Description>
        Please Type your service description here
    </Description>
    <messageReceivers>
        <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/in-only" class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver" />
        <messageReceiver  mep="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/in-out"  class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver"/>
    </messageReceivers>
    <parameter name="ServiceClass" locked="false">com.ciber.webservices.Axis2HelloWorld</parameter>
</service>
```

Answer (score 0):

update to axis2 1.7.1 solved this problem, but there now i discovered other problems... like this one:

```
[2016-03-02 11:39:47] [ERROR] [org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver] - null 
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.BeanUtil.addInstanceTypeAttribute(BeanUtil.java:1316)
at org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.BeanUtil.getPropertyQnameList(BeanUtil.java:390)
at org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.BeanUtil.getPullParser(BeanUtil.java:88)
at org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.reader.ADBXMLStreamReaderImpl.processProperties(ADBXMLStreamReaderImpl.java:989)
at org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.reader.ADBXMLStreamReaderImpl.next(ADBXMLStreamReaderImpl.java:829)
at org.apache.axis2.util.StreamWrapper.next(StreamWrapper.java:71)
```